# If $F$ and $G$ are biadjoint, how is $\operatorname{Nat}(F,F)\simeq\operatorname{Nat}(G\circ F,1)$?

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, functors

Suppose $F$ and $G$ are biadjoint functors, with some fixed unit/counit pairs. How is it that we have an isomorphism of the set of natural transformations
$$
\operatorname{Nat}(F,F)\simeq\operatorname{Nat}(G\circ F,1)?
$$
I'm used to adjoint functors being characterized by an isomorphism of hom functors like $\hom(F(-),-)\simeq\hom(-,G(-))$, but it's not clear to me how to get from a natural transformation on $F$ to one from $GF$ to the identity.

Say the adjunctions are given by a natural isomorphism $\Phi\colon\hom(F(-),-)\to\hom(-,G(-))$ with unit and counit $\eta\colon 1\to GF$ and $\epsilon \colon FG\to 1$, and $\Phi'\colon\hom(G(-),-)\to\hom(-,F(-))$ with unit and counit $\eta'\colon 1\to FG$ and $\epsilon'\colon GF\to 1$.

Comment: It is important that you specify what is the left adjoint between $F$ and $G$; if $G\dashv F$ then you can prove the statement in at least two ways

Comment: @FoscoLoregian I'm sorry, what exactly do I need to specify? All I'm assuming is that $F$ and $G$ are biadjoint by some natural isomorphisms, units, and counits. I'm fine with assuming $F\dashv G$ and $G\dashv F$? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Hmm, if $\alpha\colon F\Rightarrow F$ has component $\alpha_X$, then we get $\alpha'\colon GF\Rightarrow 1$ with components $\alpha'_X=(\Phi'_{FX,X})^{-1}(\alpha_X)$?

Comment: I just realized that you don't mean [biadjoint](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/biadjunction), but instead [ambidextrous](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ambidextrous+adjunction).

Comment: The one you wrote is an explicit way to determine an isomorphism, yes. Then you have to check a few boring things. I posted an answer appearing slightly more elegant to my eye :-)

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1370444/adjoint-squares) for a more general case.

Answer (score 4):

$\def\Nat{\textsf{Nat}}$The claim follows from the fact that, if
$$ L : {\cal C} \leftrightarrows {\cal D} : R$$
is an adjunction, then $\Nat(LH,K)\cong \Nat(H, RK)$ for all functors $H : {\cal X}\to{\cal C},K : {\cal X}\to {\cal D}$. This, in turn, follows from the fact that
$$
\begin{align}
\Nat(LH,K) &\cong\int_x {\cal D}(LHx, Kx)\\
&\cong \int_x {\cal C}(Hx, RKx)\\
&\cong\Nat(H, RK).
\end{align}
$$
Apply this result to the case $G=L, F=R=H, K=1$.

Comment: Thanks, but what does $\int_x$ mean here? I've not seen this notation before.

Comment: @AdelaideDokras $\int_{x:\mathcal{X}} \mathcal{C}(Hx,RKx)$ is the [end](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/end) of the functor $\mathcal{C}(H-,RK-):\mathcal{X}^{op}\times\mathcal{X}\to \mathsf{Set}$