# If $F$ and $G$ are adjoint functors, why are $\operatorname{Nat}(G,G)\simeq\operatorname{Nat}(F,F)$ as algebras?

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, functors

Suppose $F\colon\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{B}$ and $G\colon\mathcal{B}\to\mathcal{A}$ are adjoint functors between some $R$-linear abelian categories ($R$ a ring), via a fixed counit-unit adjunction $\epsilon\colon GF\Rightarrow 1$ and $\eta\colon 1\Rightarrow FG$. Why is the following an isomorphism of $R$-algebras?

$$
\operatorname{Nat}(G,G)\to\operatorname{Nat}(F,F):\alpha\mapsto (F\ast\epsilon)\circ (F\ast\alpha\ast F)\circ (\eta\ast F)
$$

My primary issue is I don't see how to invert it, since the counit-unit equations $F\epsilon\circ \eta F=1$ and $\epsilon G\circ G\eta=1$ don't seem to allow me to "undo" the $F\ast\epsilon$ and $\eta\ast F$ from the left and right.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1370444/adjoint-squares) for the more general case.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Thanks, those are both helpful.