# Coends and adjunctions

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, adjoint-functors

I was reading Fosco Loregian's paper *[This is the co/end, my only co/friend](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.02503)*, and here's something that I don't understand in an exercise.

The exercise is to prove that given $F: C\to D, U: D\to  C$ two functors, then $F\dashv U$ if and only if for all $G: D^{op}\times C\to E$ such that $\int^c G(Fc, c)$ or $\int^d G(d, Ud)$ makes sense, then both do and they are isomorphic, naturally in $G$.

Assuming $F\dashv U$ one can easily prove this; it's the other direction that's bugging me for the following reason. Take $G= (\hom_C(-, U(-))\circ \tau)^{op} : D^{op}\times C\to \mathbf{Set}^{op}$, where $\tau : D\times C^{op}\to C^{op}\times D$ is the obvious functor. $\mathbf{Set}^{op}$ being cocomplete, these coends always make sense, and we have

$$\int^c G(Fc,c) = \int^c \hom_C^{op}(c, UFc) = \int_c \hom_C(c,UFc) \cong \mathrm{Nat}(id_C, UF)$$

and also

$$\int^d G(c,Ud) = \int_d \hom_C(Ud, Ud) \cong \mathrm{Nat}(U,U)$$

so if both coends are indeed isomorphic, $\mathrm{Nat}(U,U) \cong \mathrm{Nat}(id_C,UF)$. But this is odd because in an adjunction, what we actually get is something like $\mathrm{Nat}(id_C, UF) \cong \mathrm{Nat}(F,F)$, not $\mathrm{Nat}(U,U)$, which will rather be isomorphic to $\mathrm{Nat}(FU, id_D)$.

Now I don't know if I made a mistake in my calculation, or simply I just found out something I didn't know about adjunctions. Which is it ? (I think I made a mistake at some point, probably when going from $\int^d$ to $\int_d$ but I don't see how: if I'm not mistaken, $\int^c T(c,c) = \int_c T^{op}(c,c)$ where, if $T: A^{op}\times A\to C$, $T^{op} : (A^{op})^{op}\times A^{op} = A\times A^{op}\to C^{op}$)

Comment: All these are isomorphic, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1370444/adjoint-squares

Comment: @ArnaudD. thank you for the very useful link, so my formula gives another proof if I made no mistake, right? (of course this proof is less illuminating than the one in the link you provided) (I started "fearing" that they were indeed isomorphic when looking at examples, free-forgetful adjunctions from algebraic categories to $\mathbf{Set}$ are particularly illuminating for instance)

Comment: Yes, I think the results in the link can be recovered as special case of the one you mention here.

Comment: @ArnaudD. : oh right I hadn't noticed the tag limits and colimits, I think you're right - how do I delete it ?

Comment: Hi, @MaximeRamzi, could you give me some hint on how to prove the isomorphism from the adjunction? Thank you!

Comment: @protossor: to be honest I don't remember what I had in mind when I wrote "easily" here. I can't think of an easy solution right now, but one could first reduce to the case where $E$ is cocomplete, then to the case where $E$ is $\mathbf{Set}$ and $G(d,c) = \hom(d,d_0)\times \hom(c_0,c)$ for some fixed $d_0,c_0$ by general abstract nonsense. For this type of functor one can then make an explicit computation and check that it is natural in $(c_0,d_0)$ so that the reduction actually works. That's certainly not what Fosco had in mind, nor what I had in mind, so if someone has a better idea..

Comment: Thank you @MaximeRamzi! Let me post a separate question if I still have no clue after spending a little more time on this.